# Problems when updating Symfony 4.4 DoctrineMigrationsBundle from 2 to 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php, symfony4, doctrine-migrations

I was running Symfony 4.4.8, and I wanted to update my project. So I ran:

```
composer update
```

It did automatically update the DoctrineMigrationsBundle (https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle) from 2.1.2 to 3.0.1.

Composer failed at first because doctrine_migrations.yaml was not compatible with the DoctrineMigrationsBundle 3.0.1, so I ran:

```
composer recipes:install --force -v
composer install
```

But: it appears that the DoctrineMigrationsBundle v 3 has a totally different configuration and does not use the "migrations_versions" SQL table anymore, but a new "doctrine_migrations_versions"-table and a new migrations directory ('%kernel.project_dir%/migrations' instead of '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations').

This means that every time you do:

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

You will get in the migration:

```
 $this->addSql('DROP TABLE migration_versions');
```

I read at https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html that you can set the table name in doctrine_migrations.yaml manually like this:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    storage:
        table_storage:
            'table_name': 'doctrine_migrations'
```

But that is of no use, because the v 3 table has an extra column "execution_time" and in the "version" column a namespace is prepended (e.g. "DoctrineMigrations\Version20200702112735.php"). So both tables are incompatible.

I can't find any information anywhere on properly upgrading DoctrineMigrationsBundle from v2 to v3.

I must say I am surprised by this, I thought that "composer update" was to be safe. Appearently, one of the symfony bundles didn't add a version limit automatically where it should if an upgrade is not possible.

So what should I do? Should I just let composer downgrade the DoctrineMigrationsBundle again? Or is there some way to get an upgrade of DoctrineMigrationsBundle from v2 to v3 to work after all?

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/master/UPGRADE.md ? theoretically, only the configs changed and those need to be updated, everything else should work as is.

Comment: I've downgraded to v2 (see https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/301) and it works again.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation about the relevant steps. Additionally, please don't use irrelevant tags - this is not a problem with Composer or Symfony

Comment: @NicoHaase I agree that it is not a composer problem, but it is related to Symfony. Symfony uses a recipe in the Doctrine Migrations Bundle (https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle) in order to integrate it in Symfony projects which differs from the original Doctrine configuration. There is not update information from v2 to v3 in the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is explained here: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/master/UPGRADE.md

If you have already update the bundle config, just run that command:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage
```

It should work.

Comment: If you look at migrations.php before/after, both configurations already use the table doctrine_migration_versions, instead of doctrine_migrations in the Symfony doctrine migrations bundle. It doesn't say how to migrate this table to a new one with the additional columns.